# How to make text on a PyQt5 QGraphicsScene scale with the window?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene

How can I create an image in PyQt5 containing text that scales with the window?

```
"""Draw text on a QGraphicsScene"""

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])


class MyScene(QMainWindow):

    rotated_layout = {
        'Chips': [
            {'Chip': 0, 'X': 256, 'Y': 0, 'Orientation': 'RtLBtT'},
            {'Chip': 1, 'X': 0, 'Y': 0, 'Orientation': 'RtLBtT'},
            {'Chip': 2, 'X': 0, 'Y': 256, 'Orientation': 'LtRTtB'},
            {'Chip': 3, 'X': 256, 'Y': 256, 'Orientation': 'LtRTtB'}
        ],
        'Width': 512,
        'Height': 512
    }

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        scene = QGraphicsScene()

        gv = QGraphicsView(scene)
        font = QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold)
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setWeight(600)
        font.setPixelSize(150)

        for i, chip in enumerate(self.rotated_layout["Chips"]):
            X, Y = chip['X'], chip['Y']
            t = QGraphicsTextItem(str(i))
            t.setPos(256 / 2 + X, 256 / 2 + Y)
            t.setFont(font)
            scene.addItem(t)

        gv.setScene(scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(gv)


## Start Qt event loop.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = MyScene()
    graph.show()
    app.exec()
```

When window is large:
[image]

and when window is small:
[image]

Comment: The graphics view framework is quite complex, and what you're asking is a bit vague. Do you want to *scale* the scene contents no matter of the view size? Then what about using [`fitInView()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView), using the scene [`sceneRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop)?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness! What I meant is that I would like the text to remain the same size relative to the size of the window. I'll give your suggestions a try.